# disable swipe in SlidingUpPanelLayout

Tags: android, slidingpanelayout

this is my SlidingPanelLayout

```
 mLayout = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);

 mLayout.addPanelSlideListener(new SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelSlideListener() {


        @Override
        public void onPanelSlide(View panel,final float slideOffset) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPanelSlide, offset " + slideOffset);






        }

        @Override
        public void onPanelStateChanged(View panel, SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState previousState, SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState newState) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPanelStateChanged " + newState);
        }
    });
```

how can i disable swipe on it i found solution say use this

```
@Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return false;
    }
```

but i dosent extend SlidingPaneLayout please don't make this question as duplicate it's different how can i disable swipe with this my code dont tell me extend  it i want to work like this any idea ot and when i dosent extend SlidingPaneLayout this code

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return false;
}
```

not work its show error so how can i disable swipe without extend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to 
[SlidingUpPanelLayout](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)

just use

```
mLayout.setEnabled(false);
```

thats all :)

Comment: I want it should work like, it should slide on touch, not on swipe. Is it possible.